# Bootstrap 4 Carousel next/prev buttons documentation

Tags: bootstrap-carousel

I have a Bootstrap 4.0.0 Carousel up and running.
Time based changes and direct selection of items *work* as expected.

But the prev/next buttons do *not* work.
Documentation says, it should be like this (example for the left/prev button):

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev" href="#carousel-id">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
```

But like that, it does not work. BUT, when I do it like that:

```
<a class="carousel-control-prev" role="button" data-slide="prev" data-target="#carousel-id">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
```

Here, when I swapped out *href* with *data-target* it works.
Why does everyone say, it should be *href*?
Can I use *data-target* then? *data-target* is used also by 'data-slide-to' button, why not with 'data-slide'? This makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had Bootstrap 4.0.0 and jQuery 2.5.x.
I upgraded to jQuery 3.5.1, now it works as expected.